# IBM ACE - Calling Oracle Procedure returning a rowtype (via ESQL compute node)

Tags: websphere, ibm-app-connect

I'm trying to call procedure stored in plsql. Here is what I've tried so far.

In Oracle:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE dbSwapParms  
( in_param IN VARCHAR2, 
  out_param OUT varchar2, 
  inout_param IN OUT customer%ROWTYPE) 
AS 
BEGIN
  select * 
  into inout_param 
  from SYS_ENDPOINTS  where customer_name=in_param; -- assuming this query returns single row
END;
```

In Compute node:

```
-- Definition of procedure  
CREATE PROCEDURE swapParms ( 
      IN parm1 CHARACTER, 
      OUT parm2 CHARACTER 
    )
    LANGUAGE DATABASE  
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 
    EXTERNAL NAME dbSwapParms;
```

-- Invoking the procedures

```
CALL swapParms( inputParm, outputParm, OutputRoot.JSON.Data.test[]); -- found this in ibm documentation returning result set
```

Here is the error:

```
BIP2230E: Error detected whilst processing a message in node 'gen.CB_testBar.postHelloWorld (Implementation).Compute4'. 
BIP2488E: ('.postHelloWorld_Compute4.Main', '19.4') Error detected whilst executing the SQL statement ''CALL swapParms(inputParm, outputParm, OutputRoot.JSON.Data.test[]);''. 
BIP2934E: Error detected whilst executing the function or procedure ''swapParms''. 
BIP2321E: Database error: ODBC return code '-1' using ODBC driver manager ''odbc32.dll''. 
BIP2322E: Database error: SQL State ''HY000''; Native Error Code '0'; Error Text ''[IBM][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]SQL type not supported: 0''.
```

I'm not sure if I've represented the oracle procedure correctly.

Comment: 1) Are you able to connect to the database normally through IBM ACE using compute node or database node.  (2)Also, do you have the statement defined in your esql. For eg. CREATE PROCEDURE myProc3(IN p1 CHAR) LANGUAGE DATABASE EXTERNAL 
                 NAME "mySchema.myPackage.myProc";      (3)Are you able to call the stored procedure independently using some client other than IBM ACE to ensure you stored procedure is working fine.

Comment: Your formatting was not correct. I have edited the question. Please click the Edit button to see what I did (after the edit has been approved, obviously)

Comment: Hi Rohan,  Yes I'm connected to the database (tested using simple query) . Also, I've tested the plsql. The only thing I'm not sure I think is the representation of the procedure in oracle to esql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by using plsql function instead of procedure. The function returns ref cursor as a result set. Then, applied the ibm documentation of invoking procedure  returning resultset.